# How upload file with selenide(java) , element <input type="file">

Tags: java, html, jsf, selenide

```
$x("//input[@type='file']").uploadFromClasspath(fileName);
```

and

```
$x("//input[@type='file']").uploadFile(new File(fileName);
```

not work, only after click on button which includes this input. But after click  on this button i can`t close select file window, because it the system window. Other variants using web driver, different switheTo and actions works only after open choose file window.

Front-end of app written in jsf using primefaces lib.

element example:

```
  <div class="ui-fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
    <span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-choose"
          role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">File</span>
        <input type="file" id="documentsSplitViewForm:attUpload_input"
               name="documentsSplitViewForm:attUpload_input" multiple="multiple">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an example:
 [FileUploadTest](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/blob/master/src/test/java/integration/FileUploadTest.java)

the main function to use is:

```
File file = $("#cv").uploadFile(new File("src/test/java/../resources/hello_world.txt"));
```